# Query with terms does not work properly

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this document in Elasticsearch (1.6)

```
{
"_index": "onkopedia",
"_type": "document_",
"_id": "0afa26afc2d1440a8ed03dac0e8511fc",
"_version": 1,
"_score": null,
"_source": {
"description": "",
"contributors": [ ],
"metaTypeName": "Connector",
"sortableTitle": "mammakarzinom der frau",
"subject": [ ],
"authorizedUsers": [
"Anonymous"
],
"language": "",
"title": "Mammakarzinom der Frau",
"url": "http://dev1.veit-schiele.de:9080/onkopedia/de/onkopedia/guidelines/mammakarzinom-der-frau",
"author": "ajung",
"modified": "2015-05-11T05:21:14",
"metaType": "xmldirector.plonecore.connector",
"content": " Mammakarzinom der Frau Stand: Januar 2013 Autoren der aktuellen .....",
"authorName": "ajung",
"created": "2015-05-11T05:21:14",
"review_state": "published"
},
"sort": [
null
]
}
```

containing a key

```
'authorizedUsers': ['Anonymous']
```

The following query is supposed to return the document above however it does not:

```
 {
  "sort": [
    "_score"
  ], 
  "from": 0, 
  "fields": [
    "url", 
    "title", 
    "description", 
    "metaType", 
    "metaTypeName", 
    "author", 
    "authorName", 
    "contributors", 
    "modified", 
    "subject", 
    "review_state", 
    "language", 
    "content"
  ], 
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "terms": {
              "execution": "or", 
              "metaType": [
                "Document", 
                "FormFolder", 
                "Collection", 
                "Discussion Item", 
                "News Item", 
                "xmldirector.plonecore.connector", 
                "CaptchaField"
              ]
            }
          }, 
          {
            "terms": {
              "execution": "or", 
              "authorizedUsers": [
                "Manager", 
                "Authenticated", 
                "Anonymous", 
                "user:ajung"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }, 
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "mammakarzinom", 
          "default_operator": "AND", 
          "fields": [
            "title^3", 
            "contributors^2", 
            "subject^2", 
            "description", 
            "content"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "content": {
        "fragment_size": 250, 
        "number_of_fragments": 3
      }, 
      "description": {
        "fragment_size": 250, 
        "number_of_fragments": 2
      }, 
      "title": {
        "number_of_fragments": 0
      }
    }
  }, 
  "size": 15
}
```

The query without the filter for 'authorizedUsers' does return the document.
Why? 'Anonymous' as value for 'authorizedUsers' is available within the query, so I would expect that the document would be found by the first query, or?

```
{
  "sort": [
    "_score"
  ], 
  "from": 0, 
  "fields": [
    "url", 
    "title", 
    "description", 
    "metaType", 
    "metaTypeName", 
    "author", 
    "authorName", 
    "contributors", 
    "modified", 
    "subject", 
    "review_state", 
    "language", 
    "content"
  ], 
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "terms": {
              "execution": "or", 
              "metaType": [
                "Document", 
                "FormFolder", 
                "Collection", 
                "Discussion Item", 
                "News Item", 
                "xmldirector.plonecore.connector", 
                "CaptchaField"
              ]
            }
          }

        ]
      }, 
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "mammakarzinom", 
          "default_operator": "AND", 
          "fields": [
            "title^3", 
            "contributors^2", 
            "subject^2", 
            "description", 
            "content"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "content": {
        "fragment_size": 250, 
        "number_of_fragments": 3
      }, 
      "description": {
        "fragment_size": 250, 
        "number_of_fragments": 2
      }, 
      "title": {
        "number_of_fragments": 0
      }
    }
  }, 
  "size": 15
}
```

Comment: Now I get it, can I have the mapping of this index...

Answer (score 1):

Probably your analyzer for `authorizedUsers` field is lowercasing the value itself. So, in your index the actual values is `anonymous` (lowercase `a`).

Try this filter:

```
     {
        "terms": {
          "execution": "or", 
          "authorizedUsers": [
            "manager", 
            "authenticated", 
            "anonymous", 
            "user:ajung"
          ]
        }
      }
```

meaning, search the index with the values that are actually there.
One more thing: `terms` is not analyzing the input text. This means that if you search for `Anonymous` then this is what it will look into the index. Since you have `anonymous` in the index, it will not match.